# Function is not populating global variable

Tags: arrays, powershell, global-variables

Here is the code snippet I am trying, the potential problem is the array which is declared outside of the function cannot be used in the `testobjarray()` function. It will display the count as zero in the function `testobjarray()`, but in `addobjects()` I am able to add the object to array and display the contents of the object.

```
$Global:objectorray = @()

function addobjects() {
  $object = New-Object PSObject
  $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value "Pradeep RN"
  $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Age" -Value 24
  $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Profession" -Value "Software Engineer"
  $objectorray += $object
  Write-Host "in addobjects function" $objectorray
}

function testobjarray() {
  Write-Host "in the another function" $objectorray.Count
}

addobjects
testobjarray
```

Comment: All of the information you need to figure this out can be found in [`Get-Help about_Scopes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes).

Comment: Note that modifying global variables in a function is not good practice, because it complicates troubleshooting. It's better to have the function return the object and do the append operation in the caller scope.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using globals if you do not have to. In this case you do not have to. Change the scope of `$objectorray` so that it is just in the script scope. Then use the return value of of your function to populate `$objectorray`. Note that I have only changed what little I needed to to make this example work.

```
$objectorray = @()

function addobjects() {
  $object = New-Object PSObject
  $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value "Pradeep RN"
  $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Age" -Value 24
  $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Profession" -Value "Software Engineer"
  $object
  Write-Host "in addobjects function" $object
}

function testobjarray() {
  Write-Host "in the another function" $objectorray.Count
}

$objectorray += addobjects
testobjarray
```

As mentioned in comments you need to have a look and understand scopes in PowerShell. The reference for this is [about_scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes). [gvee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42902808/3829407) shows how to use the global scope properly. Your issue happened because PowerShell allows variables with the same name in different scopes.

`$objectorray.Count` works inside the function `testobjarray` because of access to the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning values to the *Global* array in your `addobjects()` function

Change:

```
$objectorray+=$object
```

To:

```
$global:objectorray+=$object
```

And the same change in your `testobjarray()` function:

```
Write-Host "in the another function" $global:objectorray.Count
```